# Delete Width Height Attribute Values in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, regex, notepad++

I'm trying to delete/change width and height attributes from images in my website.

```
<img alt="xxxyyzzz" src="/images/x.jpg" style="width: 450px; height: 585px;" />

style="width: 450px; height: 585px;" attribute values in mysql database.
```

I've dumped my database and trying to change with Notepad++ by using find/replace command

```
Find What : style="width: (.*)px; height: (.*)px;" /
Replace   : /

Match Case Checked
Regular Expression Checked
```

But after change, if i try to import mysql database via phpmyadmin or mysql workbench, i am getting

> ERROR 1136 (21S01) at line 12977: Column count doesn't match value count at row 12

and can't import db.

Anybody can help me?

`style="width: (.*)px; height: (.*)px;"` right for database replace?

P.S.: I've different px sized images with using style="width: px; height: px;"

Comment: I've solved the problem with this code 'style="width: \d\d\dpx; height: \d\d\dpx;" />'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
Find What : style="width: \d+px; height: \d+px;" /
Replace   : /
```

Comment: I solved with that code 'style="width: \d\d\dpx; height: \d\d\dpx;" />'  Thanks

Comment: @JohnRock: Sure, it works too, but only if you have 3 digit width/height. Mine works with any number of digits (more than 0).